# Travelling to Bulgaria with Italian type D multi entry national visa

Tags: schengen, transit-visas, bulgaria

I have D type multi entry 365 days visa given by Italy. I want to travel from Turkey to Bulgaria by bus. Is there any problem when I pass border?
I read that Bulgaria allows travellers who have a valid Schengen visa without the requirement of Bulgarian visa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [EU Immigration Portal](http://ec.europa.eu/immigration/do-i-need-a-visa/do-i-need-a-short-stay-visa_en):

> If you hold a residence permit or a long-stay visa issued by a Schengen area country, you will have the same freedom of travel as a Schengen short-stay visa holder. If you have a Schengen visa and wish to visit any of the six EU countries which are outside the Schengen area (Bulgaria, Romania, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland, the United Kingdom), you normally need to apply for a separate national visa for each country. However, **holders of Schengen visas valid for multiple entries can enter Bulgaria**, Croatia, Cyprus and Romania without an additional national visa.

Comment: So I think I can enter the Bulgaria with D type Schengen visa. Also I found this EU decision on official Romanian ministry foreign affairs website. Here is the link;  https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040

Comment: I have a doubt about the section indicated on visa sticker that is written on top "valid for : Italia " .  I do not know why D type visa given by a Schengen country is not entitled as Schengen :(

Comment: @Kereminan: Because Italy is the only place where the visa will give you the _full_ rights it's intended to give. The tag-along right to make _short_ visits other Schengen countries is a bonus, not the core validity of the visa.

Comment: @HenningMakholm formerly there was a type of visa as D+C for long stay but it is now given as D type visa known also as national visa. Romanian MFA indicates that "Holders of Schengen visas with two or multiple entries, national visas or residence permits issued by Schengen Member States. ..;The long-stay visa issued by a Schengen member state; " i could not find any specific details for Bulgarian ministery but Romania and Bulgaria signed the same agreement as well. I do not know what to do :(

Comment: If you are from Turkey or Azerbaijan, you can't travel Cyprus with Schengen visa. http://www.mfa.gov.cy/mfa/consulate/consulate_spb.nsf/cgsp10_en/cgsp10_en?OpenDocument&print

Comment: I do not care South Cyprus but according to website link you sent Non-EU (third countries) people who have type D visa given by a Shengen member  can visit Cyprus and I made a deduction same as Bulgaria 